# How to extract youtube video id with Regex.Match

Tags: regex, vb.net, vb.net-2010, matching

i try to extract video ID from youtube using Regex.Match, for example I have www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lqexxxCoDo and i want to extract only 3lqexxxCoDo.

```
    Dim link_vids As Match = Regex.Match(url_comments.Text, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(.*?)$")

    url_v = link_vids.Value.ToString
    MessageBox.Show(url_v)
```

how i can extract video id ?, thanks !

Comment: You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` in .NET to just grab the `v` query string value without messing with Regex. Something like `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)("v")` Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution

```
Dim Str() As String
        Str = url_comments.Text.Split("=")
        url_v = Str(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function getID(url as String) as String
    Try
        Dim myMatches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match 'Varible to hold the match
        Dim MyRegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 'This is where the magic happens/SHOULD work on all normal youtube links including youtu.be
        myMatches = MyRegEx.Match(url)
        If myMatches.Success = true then
            Return myMatches.Groups(1).Value
        Else
            Return "" 'Didn't match something went wrong
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.ToString
    End Try
End Function
```

This function will return just the video ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can basically replace "www.youtube.com/watch?v=" with "" using "String.Replace"

[MSDN String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
url.Replace("www.youtube.com/watch?v=","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression, in PHP I am using this.

```
function parseYtId($vid)
{
    if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $vid, $match)) {
        $vid = $match[1];
    }
    return $vid;
}
```